# how to set the shm size where i using a docker on kubersphere

Tags: docker

RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 39477) is killed by signal: Bus error. It is possible that dataloader's workers are out of shared memory. Please try to raise your shared memory limit.

when i train the DL model on a docker, which is deployed on kubersphere, raised above error messages.

i added below but did not work for me

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: your-container-name
    securityContext:
      shmSize: "64Mi" # 例如，分配64兆字节的共享内存
```